# How to call Angular's internal email validation method

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to call Angular's internal email validation method from JavaScript rather than declarative in the markup?

Thank you.

*EDIT:*

To answer all, the reason I am looking for this is so that email validation is consistent when using both the normal `<input type="email"/>` validation as well as when using programmatic validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this question because I had to validate an input field where users can enter a *list* of email addresses.
So I wrote a custom directive that is placed on a "regular" email input:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('listOfEmails', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.listofemails = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue,
            length, i;
        if ( ! angular.isDefined(value) ) {
          return true;
        }
        length = value.length;
        for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
          if ( ! ngModel.$validators.email(value[i]) ) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        //if nothing is invalid, it's valid:
        ngModel.$setValidity('email', true);
        return true; 
    };
  }
});
```

And in the HTML:

`<input type="email" ng-list ng-model="addresses" list-of-emails  name="toAdresses" />`

Depending on your concrete usecase you may mock something up with this or with custom form controls: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-

Comment: Quite clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.  Angular uses a series of custom regular expressions to validate emails, numbers, etc on form elements.  You see the source for that [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L248).

The regex they use on `<input type="email">` elements (in 1.2.14) is as follows:

```
var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i;
```

But there isn't any way to access that regex programatically.

Comment: Thanks tennisgent, I need to be able to use the built-in one so that it's consistent between using the `<input type="email"/>` and JavaScript validation. I could grap the RegExp there and keep updating it if it changes when Angular gets updated, but that's not ideal.

Comment: I understand why you'd want it to be consistent, but the fact remains that Angular just doesn't make their validator accessible from outside its own code.  There is no `angular.emailValidator()` or anything that you can access, so you're probably going to have to settle for a `"not ideal"` solution.